# On clicking predict button, the app crashes

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

Recently I have been working on android studio, I built a python image classification model and want to integrate it with an app. But when I click on predict button, the app crashes. Would be helpful if I can get the idea as to where things are going wrong.
Attached is the code and the error it throws -
Activitymain.java :-

```
package com.example.uni;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.uni.ml.ConvertedModel;

import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imgView;
    private Button predict;
    private Button select;
    private TextView tv;
    private Bitmap img;



    @Override
    protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        predict = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,12);

            }
        });

        predict.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img,
                        500,
                        500,
                        true);

                try {
                    ConvertedModel model = ConvertedModel.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

                    // Creates inputs for reference.
                    TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 500, 500, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);

                    TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);
                    tensorImage.load(img);
                    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = tensorImage.getBuffer();


                    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

                    // Runs model inference and gets result.
                    ConvertedModel.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
                    TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

                    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                    model.close();


                    tv.setText((int) outputFeature0.getFloatArray()[0]);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    /* TODO Handle the exception */
                }

            }
        });





    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 100)
        {
            imgView.setImageURI(data.getData());

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                img = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In logcat I see this -

```
    2021-11-05 13:23:38.040 24027-24027/com.example.uni I/tflite: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
2021-11-05 13:23:38.090 24027-24027/com.example.uni E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"
2021-11-05 13:23:38.081 24027-24027/com.example.uni W/com.example.uni: type=1400 audit(0.0:232245): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14249 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c48,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2021-11-05 13:23:38.841 24027-24027/com.example.uni E/com.example.un: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-11-05 13:23:38.842 24027-24027/com.example.uni D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-11-05 13:23:38.843 24027-24027/com.example.uni E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.uni, PID: 24027
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:381)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6397)
        at com.example.uni.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:85)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7189)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7166)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:819)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27682)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2021-11-05 13:23:38.887 24027-24027/com.example.uni I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24027 SIG: 9
```

Need suggestions as to what's going on and how to resolve it. I'm using android studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 patch 3.

Comment: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID` - you should be able to debug using this.

Answer (score 0):

The logcat already told you that it crashed at the `setText()` call. You called

```
tv.setText((int) outputFeature0.getFloatArray()[0]);
```

The `int` in [setText(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)) refers to a Resource ID defined in the string.xml (`R.string.xxx`).

If you are not getting the string from res, you should use [setText(CharSequence)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) instead.

You probably want

```
tv.setText(String.format("%f",outputFeature0.getFloatArray()[0]));
```

(change "%f" to any decimal points or format you want)

Comment: Ok, so please correct me if I'm wrong. What i understood from this is it needed string whereas we had fed integer. Adding 'string.format' is basically telling it to get the integer value. This answer helps as the predict button works now. Thanks a lot!!